# How to calculate current at one circuit node in a textbook exercise

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

I'm going through this book on my own, trying to teach myself and I've come to this problem and I can't figure out how to solve it.

I'm supposed to determine I<sub>x</sub>, assuming R<sub>1</sub> = 1 kΩ and R<sub>2</sub> = 2 kΩ. In a previous question I've determined that V<sub>1</sub> = 10 V and V<sub>2</sub> = -42 V.

I know that I<sub>x</sub> = 8 mA, what I need help with is why it is 8mA and how to come to that answer?

[image: circuit p1-21]

I gave the solution so you know I'm not just trying to get you to do my homework. I determined V<sub>1</sub> and V<sub>2</sub>. I'm taking the initiative to teach myself, I'm autistic, and the book has never given a circuit like this before and I don't have a teacher to ask for help.

My only attempt was squaring the voltages across R<sub>1</sub> and R<sub>2</sub> then dividing them by the respective resistances. I got 0.576 and 0.512, and if you subtract 0.512 from 0.576 you get 0.064, and the square-root of 64 is 8. I'm pretty sure that isn't anywhere near correct.

Comment: All you need is a KCL at Ix node  [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=32%2F2+%2B+x+-+24%2F1+%3D+0+)

Comment: Use Ohm's law on R1 and R2, then Kirchhoff's current law.

Comment: Use the equation V= IR to calculate potential difference acrross a resistor. Use that to calculate current in each resistor. Use KCL to find \$I_x\$ at junction where . \$I_x\$ meets the electric network. Sum of all currents meeting at a junction would be zero. The direction of current towards the junction is positive and the current opposite to the junction is negative.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know to use KCL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe a little visual drawing will help.
You can easily calculate the currents in each resistor using Ohms Law.
Then using Kirchhoff's current law, all the currents in a node must sum to 0.
Note: The arrow directions are arbitrary.  If the actual current flow is in the opposite direction of the arrow, then you'll get a negative number.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZGEpu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>